# How to i18n parameters in message resources

Tags: java, spring, validation

Is there a elegant way to do this?
message resources like this:

```
label.username=User Name
error.empty={0} is mandatory
error.duplicate={0} is duplicate
info.name=name
```

I want to make {0} i18n. that means it will show error message like "name is mandatory", and if user change his locale, then the whole error message will change, not only "is mandatory".

```
public class UserValidator implements Validator{

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;


    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return User.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        User user = (User)target;
        List<User> ul = userService.getUsersByName(user.getName());
        if(ul.size() > 0){
            String argName = i18n("info.name");
            errors.reject("error.duplicate",new Object[]{argName}, null);
        }

    }

    private String i18n(String messageKey) {
        // TODO get message from message resources
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the Validator and Errors interfaces I can't see any direct link to a MesssageSource to get the i18n messages. The Errors interface just takes a single key. Apparently you have to autowire an instance of MessageSource and get the translations in two steps:

```
public class UserValidator implements Validator{

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return User.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        User user = (User)target;
        List<User> ul = userService.getUsersByName(user.getName());
        if(ul.size() > 0){
            String argName = i18n("info.name");
            errors.reject("error.duplicate",new Object[]{argName}, null);
        }
    }

    private String i18n(String messageKey) {
        return messageSource.getMessage(messageKey, null, getLocale();
    } 
}
```

Now the thing is to provide the Locale somehow. This you will have to figure out for yourself, depending on how you want to manage your dependencies for this Validator. If you can't provide one, Spring will get the default one, but I'm guessing you need it in the end.

If you need help preparing the MessageSource instance just get back to me and leave a comment and I'll give you some code. If you want to manage by yourself, [here](http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-messagesource/) is a tutorial.